# Restrict direct url access in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am developing business application by using struts2.
I'd like to restrict direct url accessing.
If the user is accessed an action by browser url direct access, not click the link,
I'd like to show the error page.(You can't use url direct access.)

If someone have the solution, please share to me.
Thank you.

Comment: Can I just ask why you don't want the user to be able to access the ressources directly by the address bar? (if he has all the credentials)

Comment: I have to control the accessing security in the application. The user can only use or access the application by using link or button ui control in the application. The user can't access the application by url direct access.

Comment: If you can access with "click the link" what makes different from it to access it "by browser url direct access"? Could you clarify it? Do you have a code example to demonstrate your understanding of the problem? What is a security do you want to have access control?

Comment: I don't want to allow that The user can access directly the url in the browser. for example: http://wwww.example.com/sampleaction.action or http://wwww.example.com/sampleaction.action?id=1. But the user can browse the login page of the application firstly by http://wwww.example.com, and then the user will use the application by clicking the link or button.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is strange & I don't understand the reason behind.

But let me explain on how such a functionality can be attained :

1. When a direct url-request is being made, then the `Referer` header is not present in the request.
2. You can simply write an interceptor that checks whether the incoming request has the `Referer` header & it comes from your domain. If no, then you can send error if yes then continue.

Although it's easily possible to by-pass this, but majority of your users won't be doing this.

Sample Interceptor Code :

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request =
                (HttpServletRequest) ai.getInvocationContext().get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
        if (request != null) {
            if (request.getHeader("Referer") == null) {
                return "error";
            }
            return ai.invoke();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User can makes a request, which is a url.

This url can be called

1. By clinking a link
2. Submitting a form
3. Manually type URL in address bar
4. Make a request by using some libraries like commons-http
5. .....

They are many ways. You can not make sure which one should be used. You server (Struts Action) receives these request and process them.

Even if you could identify the request cam from a link or button, you can not trust it. A hacker can easily mimic the request object came from different sources.

I believe you are not in the correct path. Or please explain more.

Comment: I means No.3 Manually type URL in address bar. Our url have the parameter value. So, the user can know the parameter value. I want to restrict the url access like that. The user can access firstly www.example.com. After that, the user use the application by clicking the link or submitting a form.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no way you can restrict where the request is come from, user can easily create a request and send it to your server. I believe you are making a bad security design strategy in your project.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can check the session for particular values, so that to confirm that the request is an authorized one, you can even check for some values in the request , you can use hidden fields in JSP for this purpose.The value checking can be done in the method `prepare()` ,in the action, which will be executed every time when action is called, so before rendering the jsp ,you can easily redirect to any page by writing logic in the prepare method.To use the prepare method you want to implement the `Preparable` interface